# In Ubuntu WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause, While trying to pull data from SQL Database to Elasticsearch

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, elasticsearch

While trying to pull data from SQL Database to elasticsearch using logstash, I got this problem

> WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]

Comment: So if `sqljdbc_auth.dll` is not in the directories listed in the error message then which directory is it in? Have you tried adding that directory to your `-Djava.library.path=...` parameter?

Comment: I have tried this  java -Djava.library.path='/home/ajeeth/Documents/myjarfile/sqljdbc_auth.dll' but didn't work

Comment: Don't include the actual filename in that parameter, it's meant to be a list of folders that contain your various library files. On Linux that's a :-separated list of directories, on Windows it would be ;-separated.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response, but problem didn't solve

Answer (score 0):

actually, I was not very familiar with SQL server, the mistake was is SQL Server HOST Name, I have tested fetching more than 7k records. this setting works for me.

```
    input {
    jdbc {
           jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/mssql-jdbc-7.3.1.jre8-preview.jar"
           jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
           jdbc_connection_string =>"jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1435;databaseName=CMS;user=rot;password=234;"
           jdbc_user => "aje"
           jdbc_password => "1234"
           #schedule => "* * * * *" 
           statement => "SELECT * FROM vwWebsiteSearch"
           clean_run=>true
    }
    }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost:9200"
      index => "mysearch"
    }
    stdout{}
    }
```